# Elastic Search Browser Connectivity

Tags: elastic-stack

I have Elastic Search installed on my CentOS 7 machine .

I  am able to hit the link using CURL command.

But when I am trying to connect on browser using "localhost:9200" , it says "Connection refused".

Answer (score 0):

bind your network_host to 0.0.0.0
network.host: 0.0.0.0